# All org info lost every time after computer reboot

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, scratch-org, dev-hub

so I can connect to the DevHub, spin up scratch orgs without any issue. And when I ran sfdx force:org:list, everything is listed as it should
but every time after I reboot my (work) computer, sfdx force:org:list gives me no connected org. I have to re-auth Devhub, either create new scratch org or re-auth the existing one. it's just so time consuming everyday.
we are on Virtual Desktop (VDI) if this helps.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to contact your IT department. Authorization data is stored in a set of files stored in $HOME/.sfdx or %HOMEPATH$.sfdx. If your system isn't configured to save or migrate this data between sessions, that would be why you're losing the authentication data. There's a large number of reasons why this could happen, but whatever it is, we can't help you. You need the help of your IT department to figure out what's going on. It could be anything from software (e.g. Norton Ghost) to a configuration issue (e.g. incorrectly figured roaming profiles), or something else entirely.

Comment: this helps a lot, especially the info where the files are stored. Thanks.